# Storing/ Exporting Selenium Webdriver Test Results

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Im using Eclipse - TestNG / Webdriver, and doing regression testing my application and getting the test results, so is there any way that i can store the test results(i.e, whaterver the printed output), can i export in any format like XL file or HTML whenever i run the tests?

Answer (score 0):

If your tests executed successfully, than you can see output in location:: project-directory/test-output

Refer to these files:

1. index.html  => Full TestNg HTML reports
2. emailable-report.html => Reports that can be easily printed and emailed
3. testng-results.xml  => TestNg results in xml format

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind, why do you want to store them?
If they pass, test results should be ignoreable.

And if they don't pass, don't you need to fix the one that failed? (and therefore just run the test that failed manually while looking through it?).

Comment: Yes, thats fine, but if i wanted to generate a report on a weekly basis or every iteration, that how many times the test failed or passed, like creating metrics. And also i have come up with this question in an interview, so i felt its better to know, then simply leaving it. And also you could post this as a comment, not an answer here.

Comment: Sorry about that I am new to posting on the site. That makes sense and I must try do this myself for practice. I can see now how it would be useful to see metrics for failed tests to look at overall patterns.